# MPI: simultaneous process communication (send/receive) between independent (non overlapping) process pairs

Tags: c, multiprocessing, mpi, openmpi

i want to simultaneously transfer data between multiple processes and i have an idea how to do it but maybe there are hidden pitfalls i do not see.

In the following MPI example i have 6 processes (numbered from 0 to 5) and i want to send a MPI_DOUBLE value from 0 to 1 and from 2 to 3 and from 4 to 5.
There is obviously no overlap so it should be possible to do all three transfers at the same time (simultaneously) right? I do not want the other 4 processes to wait until 0 and 1 are finished before 2 to 3 starts and so on.
Here is my example solution:

```
int rankid; // 0,..,5
double sendb, recvb;

if (rankid%6 == 0) { // processes 0,2,4
    MPI_Send(&sendb, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else {
    MPI_Recv(&recvb, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

In this code the send and receive processes have their own paths and it should technically be possible to have each pair doing their communication simultaneously. But does this really work in practice? Are there maybe some technical problems depending on the hardware or something like that?
I am naively expecting that there are kind of three non intersected lanes, each totally independent from the others, but probably that it not the case. Maybe there is some central node every transferred information has to pass through?

I have created a little bit more complex application like that, and i noticed that running the same program on my home pc (one cpu with 6 threads) is way faster than on a larger cluster computer (6 nodes with 16 threads each = 96 processes in total).

Comment: Yes, there are capacity issues. But, in order to discuss them, it would help if you could post more [i.e. all] of your code to provide a better context. At a minimum, where is the main process loop? Alternate ranks need to recv/send and the others do recv. There are efficiency limits when more threads/processes are involved.

Comment: There is no main loop, all ranks are equal. But in practice there are much more ranks, the pairs are not really disjunctive.

Comment: The paired send/recv does _not_ wait for a different pair, but having 96 processes may swamp the NIC capacity. Also, the memory bus/system will get maxxed out after about four threads [*], so you may want to limit things. You may want to build a test app that benchmarks the given system and determines the optimal tuning number for that system, which you could save in a config file. [*] See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1obZeHnAwz4&t=1251 It's part two of a CppCon video talk about lockless, but the guy knows his stuff and mentions the four thread limit